# Actionscript 3: Dynamically build arrayobjects from arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, object, dynamically-generated

What I want my function todo is to return an dynamically generated array that I then can assign to the value of an object parameter, e.g:

```
var varObj:Object = {
    level:level,
    scores:getScoreArray()
}

function getScoreArray():Object {
    return[
        for each(var i:score in myScoreArray){
        //append i to the return-array
        }
    ];
}
```

The resulting varObj should then look something like:

```
{level:12,scores:[150,240,550]}
```

thanks in advance
Jery

EDIT: So this is what vesper´s answer got me:

```
private function getTrialsArray():Array {
    var array:Array = new Array();

    for each(var model:TrialTrackingModel in trialTrackingArray) {
        array.push({
            level:model.level,
            stimulustime:model.stimmulusTime,
            inputMethod:model.inputMethod,
            reactionTimes:model.reactionTimes.slice(),
            answers:model.answers.slice()
        });
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically create a new array in that function, populate it, then return the readied array. Like this:

```
function getScoreArray():Array {
    var a:Array=[];
    for each(var i in myScoreArray){
    a.push[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

In fact, this can be done with more ease using `Array:slice()` function.

```
function getScoreArray():Array { return myScoreArray.slice(); }
```

Comment: haha damn, didnt think of something like this. I´ll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to do so. Thanks

Comment: cant use slice, because I was oversimplifing my use-case, but that would be a neat option, for something as simple as a score array

Comment: There's more. Populating the array out of oyur array is a flexible thing, as you can filter out unneeded objects. Using `slice()` returns a copy of the array without any filtering, but is faster.

Comment: I edited my question to let you see what I acutally did. Slice definitly came in handy. thanks alot. still can´t accept your answer for another 8 mins or so